# How to generate CSR with Public Key exponent and modulus only using CertificateRequest in C#

Tags: c#, csr

Trying to generate a CSR. so I only have public key exponent and modulus since the private key is in HSM.
So i generate an RSA object to pass CertificateRequest.

```
public static RSA GetRsaPublicKey(byte[] modulus, byte[] exponent)
{
    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    RSAParameters keyInfo = new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus = modulus,
        Exponent = exponent
    };

    rsa.ImportParameters(keyInfo);

    return rsa;
}
```

But when calling CreateSigningRequest() or CreateSelfSigned() methods it throws exception:

> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException:
> 'Key does not exist.'

The tried to use this overload [CertificateRequest(X500DistinguishedName, PublicKey, HashAlgorithmName)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-certificaterequest-ctor(system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x500distinguishedname-system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-publickey-system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithmname)).
But unable to construct PublicKey 2nd argument.

I then found this method but getting this error:

```
var gen = X509SignatureGenerator.CreateForRSA(rsa, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
var req = new CertificateRequest(new X500DistinguishedName(subject), gen.PublicKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
var bytes = req.CreateSigningRequest();//exception thrown
```

> This method cannot be used since no signing key was provided via a
> constructor, use an overload accepting an X509SignatureGenerator
> instead.

Any help plz? on how to create a CSR without private key.

Answer (score 1):

Certification Signing Requests contain the public key, but they are signed with the private key to prove that the private key holder authorized the options included in the request.

If you know that the CA you are sending the request to isn’t going to verify the signature, you could make a custom X509SignatureGenerator that produces the right algorithm identifier, but just writes a gibberish signature.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @bartonjs.
Here is my solution that worked based on this: https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography/System/Security/Cryptography/X509Certificates/X509SignatureGenerator.cs

```
public class CustomX509SignatureGenerator : X509SignatureGenerator
{
    private readonly byte[] publicKey;

    public CustomX509SignatureGenerator(byte[] publicKey)
    {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
    }

    protected override PublicKey BuildPublicKey()
    {
        Oid oid = new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.1.1");

        // The OID is being passed to everything here because that's what X509Certificate2.PublicKey does.
        return new PublicKey(
            oid,
            // Encode the DER-NULL even though it is OPTIONAL, because everyone else does.
            //
            // This is due to one version of the ASN.1 not including OPTIONAL, and that was
            // the version that got predominately implemented for RSA. Now it's convention.
            new AsnEncodedData(oid, stackalloc byte[] { 0x05, 0x00 }),
            new AsnEncodedData(oid, this.publicKey));
    }

    // https://source.dot.net/#System.Security.Cryptography/Oids.cs,2f70bfb7d65ebf89,references
    public override byte[] GetSignatureAlgorithmIdentifier(HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm)
    {
        var oid = "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11";

        AsnWriter writer = new AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER);
        writer.PushSequence();
        writer.WriteObjectIdentifier(oid);
        writer.WriteNull();
        writer.PopSequence();
        return writer.Encode();
    }

    // Gibberish
    public override byte[] SignData(byte[] data, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm)
    {
        return new byte[2] { 0xAA, 0xBB };
    }
}

// then call 
 var csrBytes = req.CreateSigningRequest(new CustomX509SignatureGenerator(rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey()));
```